# Как лучше всего получать комментарии к посту?

Tags: php

Как сделать ленту, как в ВК, чтобы возле всех постов внизу отображалась часть комментариев. 
На серверы мы получаем все посты

```
$posts = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC"));
```

потом в HTML

```
  <?foreach($posts as $post):?>
   //код
   $comments = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = $post['id']"));
   <?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: А что значит - лучше? Я, например, делал так:
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comm` WHERE `cidtask` = '$_GET[task]' ORDER BY `cdate` DESC");
                while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
echo $comment[ctext];
}?>

Comment: нет понимаете, постов много и не при клике, что-бы они отображались, а при загрузке страницы, как в ВК

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы некорректно ставите задачу. Что значит "при загрузке страницы"? Чтобы комментарии загружались тогда, когда Вы переходите на страницу? Тогда мой вариант подходит.
Если Вы хотите, чтобы комментарии загружались без перезагрузки страницы (нажав кнопку "добавить", комментарий добавляется, сразу видим, но страница не перезагружается), тогда необходимо использовать Ajax.
В любом случае, имеет смысл подробнее описать Вашу задачу...

Comment: я так понимаю ему в пред. просмотре (ну или списке постов) надо показать несколько первых (либо последних) комментариев, а все показывать только в режиме просмотра поста

Comment: @Seyran, видимо да. Он отредактировал задачу и стало несколько понятней. 
Можно, например, SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comments = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = $post['id'] ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант при отображении страницы выгружать не все комментарии а лишь первые 10

```
$comments = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT Top 10 * FROM comments WHERE id_post = $post['id']"));
```